# Change custom control default Text property at design time

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I created a user control. It's basically a button with some custom properties.

```
public partial class CustomButton : Button {
    // My custom properties, constructor and events
}
```

Everytime I add this `CustomButton` on a form, its default `Text` value is set to "*customButtonX*", where X is 1, 2, 3, ...

How can I change this value? I would like it to be "*buttonX*" (X = 1, 2, 3...).

**EDIT :** I would like the trick (or whatever it is I have to do) to be active when I add a button on a form via the design view also. Meaning when I drag-drop a `CustomButton` from my toolbox to a form, its `Text` value should be "*buttonX*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drag a control from the Toolbox to a form there are some events that are triggered. In your case you have to subscribe to the one that is fired when the text property of your control is changed from String.Empty to the default name and change it. To do this you have to get the service that exposes these events (an implementation of IComponentChangeService) before the control is added to the form. This can be done overriding the Site property of your control. Modifying the example that you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice.aspx), this kind of code should work:

```
    private IComponentChangeService _changeService;

    public override System.ComponentModel.ISite Site
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Site;
        }
        set
        {
            _changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
            if (_changeService != null)
                _changeService.ComponentChanged -= new ComponentChangedEventHandler(OnComponentChanged);
            base.Site = value;
            if (!DesignMode)
                return;
            _changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
            if (_changeService != null)
                _changeService.ComponentChanged += new ComponentChangedEventHandler(OnComponentChanged);
        }
    }

    private void OnComponentChanged(object sender, ComponentChangedEventArgs ce)
    {
        CustomButton aBtn = ce.Component as CustomButton;
        if (aBtn == null || !aBtn.DesignMode)
            return;
        if (((IComponent)ce.Component).Site == null || ce.Member == null || ce.Member.Name != "Text")
            return;
        if (aBtn.Text == aBtn.Name)
            aBtn.Text = aBtn.Name.Replace("customButton", "button");
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be the right way to go. I can't make it work with the `OnComponentAdded` event though. Nothing happens when I have the `aBtn.Text = aBtn.Name.Replace("customButton", "button");` code in the event.

Comment: I used ComponentChanged because the component is first added, and its Text property is changed only after OnComponentAdded is executed. You can see what's happening adding some MessageBoxes in the methods attached to the different events.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to change the `Name` property also?

Comment: The right way to do this wuld be to implement your own version of [INameCreationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.inamecreationservice.aspx). For instance you can take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx) or [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AK2976.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The default is "yourControlNameX" thats right. But you can replace the name in the constructor.

**Note that this only will work at Runtime (not at design time)**

```
public partial class CustomButton : Button {
    // My custom properties, constructor and events

    public CustomButton() 
    {  
         this.Text = this.Text.Replace("customButton ", "button");
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, `Text` is still *customButtonX*. At least when adding a `CustomButton` on a form via the Design view.

Comment: It doesn't work because in design mode, when you add the control to the form, it is created first (and the constructor is executed), and THEN the Text is changed from the empty string to the default name.

Comment: BTW, it's useless even at runtime, since the value you set at design time (and this is the default value if you don't change it) is written in the InitializeComponent. This means that even at runtime the text you set in the constructor is overridden.

Answer (score 3):

Just override the text and set whatever you want into it.

```
public partial class CustomButton  : Button {

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            //return custom text
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            //modify value to suit your needs
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: But how can I use that to keep the *buttonX*, X=1,2,3... scheme?

Comment: If you place a debug in the set, you will see that `customButtonX` is being set via the `value`. You can remove it from the value here. Like `base.Text = value.Replace("customButton ", "button")`;

Comment: I see, it works. But that doesn't really change the default value. It changes the value *everytime*. Now, if a developer wanted to set the `CustomButton` Text value to *customButtonToDoSmthg*, that would rename the button to *buttonToDoSmthg*. I know, that's silly, but...

Comment: A simple hack you can try is to name your class `Button`. like `public partial class Button  : System.Windows.Forms.Button {`. Note, I have not tried this, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to name my class `Button` -> `Circular base class dependency involving 'Button' and 'Button'`. Can't hack! :)

Comment: Sure, you can hack it like that, you just have to make sure that your Button class is in a different namespace, and that the class to inherit is fully qualified as `System.Windows.Forms.Button`. Although it's a moot point now, as you've gotten a better answer from Francesco.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could use a ControlDesigner and set the Text property after inizialized.

```
public class MultiDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public MultiDesigner()
    {

    }

    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);

        ICommonControl control = this.Component as ICommonControl;
        control.Text = control.Tag.ToString();
    }
}
```

decorate your control with..

```
[Designer("MultiPuntoDeVenta.Controls.Tickets.Editors.Designer.MultiDesigner, MultiPuntoDeVenta.Controls")]
public class LabelBase<T> : KryptonLabel, ICommonControl where T : ICommonControl
{
.....
```