# How to expose TextBox Text Property in a User Control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I hope someone can help with what I am sure must be a stupid error on my part.

I have striped a user control I am working on down to its basic elements. I have placed a Text box on a User Control and to expose the TextBox Text property I have created the following

```
[Browsable(true)]
    public override string Text 
    { 
        get
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }
        
        set
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
        }
    
    }
```

Everything appears to work fine with one exception. When I place the control on the form the TextBox displays the name of the Control i.e. Control 1.
I have tried setting the properties Default Attribute as follows to no affect.

```
DefaultValue((string)null),
```

How can I stop the control from displaying the control name?

Thank you in advice for any guidance.

Comment: Don't override the `Control.Text` property. Implement your own custom text property, like `MyUserControlText` instead. The visual design surface is calling the `Text` property when the control is added to the design surface. (Or look into handling `IsDesignMode`).

Comment: See [Change custom control default Text property at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823913/change-custom-control-default-text-property-at-design-time).

Comment: Mark - Thank you for your response. I had already utilised that solution successfully but ideally wanting to keep the same Text parameter name that everyone is familiar with on controls

Comment: Thank you for the comment regarding IComponentChangeService. I was unaware of this and have been experimenting utilising https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice?view=net-5.0. I then amended the example to a textBox. In both cases I managed to amend the name but have been unable to amend the tBox.Text. I have been tried to access the tBox Text by "ComponentClass com = ce.Component as ComponentClass ; com.tBox1.Text = null; I have also tried comp Text = null; but neither works. I am unsure if this is correct method or what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for this problem is a custom [`ParentControlDesigner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) where you can override the [`InitializeNewComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner.initializenewcomponent?view=netframework-4.8) method to set or clear the `Text` property.

**Example**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace YourProject
{
    [DefaultProperty(nameof(Text))]
    [DefaultEvent(nameof(TextChanged))]
    [Designer(typeof(MyUserControlDesigner))]
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Update the base.Text whenever the TextBox.Text property is changed.
            textBox1.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (textBox1.Text != Text) Text = textBox1.Text;
            };
        }

        // Get and set the text of the base property instead of the TextBox's
        // to get the TextChanged event raised.
        [Browsable(true),
            EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
            DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public override string Text
        {
            get => base.Text;
            set => base.Text = value;
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the TextBox.Text property whenever the base property is changed.
            if (Text != textBox1.Text) textBox1.Text = Text;
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }

        // If you need to handle the TextChanged event...
        /// <inheritdoc cref="Control.TextChanged"/>
        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public new event EventHandler TextChanged
        {
            add { base.TextChanged += value; }
            remove { base.TextChanged -= value; }
        }
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public class MyUserControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
    {
        public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
        {
            base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);

            if (Component is MyUserControl c) c.Text = "StephenH"; // c.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and the fully functioning sample code. It makes it easier and much less dispiriting to be able to exam a functioning example. Is there any good resources available so that I can understand this more fully as it is very much new area for me? @dr.null

Comment: @StephenH You're welcome. Well, yes, the [SOURCE CODE](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) & The good books.

Comment: @StephenH There was a wrong class attribute (`DefaultValue` is a property attr.) The correct one is `DefaultProperty`. Please fix that in your version.